# windows use wmi to set network configuration

Tags: windows, networking, powershell

I recently work on a project that needs to set network info automatically after installing windows system. I did this use powershell script, but there is no default network adapter like *etho* in linux, so I have to set all network adapter to the same ip/dns/etc. Here is the code:

```
$nic1IP=[string] $args[0]
$nic1Mask=[string] $args[1]
$nic1GW=[string] $args[2]

if ( ("$nic1IP" -ne $null) -and ("$nic1Mask" -ne $null) )
{
    $wmiList=[Array](get-wmiobject -class win32_networkadapterconfiguration -filter ipenabled=true -computername .)
    foreach ($nicItem in $wmiList)
    {  
        $nicItem.EnableStatic($nic1IP, $nic1Mask)
    if ( "$nic1GW" -ne $null)
    {
            $nicItem.SetGateways($nic1GW)
    }
    }
}
```

The problem is: sometimes it won't work!

my question is, is there a way to set windows default wired network(like eth0 in linux)?

Many thx?

Comment: How come "it won't work"? What happens then? Nothing? Wrong adapter is being configured? Your system freezes? Something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `win32_networkadapterconfiguration` return all the network adaptaters. You can first use Win32_NetworkAdapter to filter the adaptaters you want to work with.

for example :

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapter -Filter "AdapterTypeId=0 AND speed>500000000"
```

gives `AdapterType` with value *Ethernet 802.3* (AdapterTypeId=0) and  *speed>500000000* allow me to eliminate WIFI ethernet interface, but most of the time I use NetConnectionID wich is the name you can give to the interface (kind of eth0)

```
$networkAdapter = Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapter -Filter "NetConnectionID='NET1'"
```

[image]

Once you adapter choosen you can choose the network configuration

```
get-wmiobject -class win32_networkadapterconfiguration -Filter "index=$($networkAdapter.Index)"
```